# How to redirect Python's subprocess.call() output to file?

Tags: python

I call an exe tool from Python:

```
args = '-i' + inputFile
cl = ['info.exe', args]
subprocess.call(cl)
```

How would I redirect output from the info.exe to `out.txt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redirect output to file object by specifying it as `stdout` argument to [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call). Put it in a context manager to write to file safely.

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    subprocess.call(cl, stdout=f)
```

Or open the file in wb mode and use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
with open('out.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(subprocess.check_output(cl))
```